# Store an Array of Hashes where keys are in order

Tags: perl

I am sorting and storing my array of hashes using this code.

```
    my @sorted_data;
        for my $k (sort keys %data) {
          push @sorted_data, { duplicates => $k, refs => join( ',', @{ $data{$k} } )};
        }
```

However, the keys need to be ordered and they are not.

Output:

```
    print Dumper \@sorted_data;

    $VAR1 = [
              {
                'refs' => 'AMD,ANF',
                'duplicates' => '(111) 111-9355'
              },
              {
                'duplicates' => '(111) 111-9385',
                'refs' => 'no ref'
              },
              {
                'refs' => 'Z1Z',
                'duplicates' => '(111) 111-2493'
              },
              {
                'duplicates' => '(111) 111-4588',
                'refs' => 'no ref'
              }
         ]
```

As you can see duplicates and refs are sometimes reversed and I need them to be in the same order every time.

Desired Output:

```
    $VAR1 = [
                  {
                    'duplicates' => '(111) 111-9355',
                    'refs' => 'AMD,ANF'
                  },
                  {
                    'duplicates' => '(111) 111-9385',
                    'refs' => 'no ref'
                  },
                  {
                    'duplicates' => '(111) 111-2493',
                    'refs' => 'Z1Z'
                  },
                  {
                    'duplicates' => '(111) 111-4588',
                    'refs' => 'no ref'
                  }
             ]
```

Yes, that is how I am producing my structure but my dump looks like this and its reflected in the export.

```
[ 
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-2493", refs => "Z1Z" },
  { duplicates=> "(111) 111-4588", refs => "no ref" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-9355", refs => "AMD,ANF" },
  { ref=> "no ref", duplicates => "(111) 111-9385" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-9356", refs => "AMD" },
  { ref=> "no ref", duplicates => "(111) 111-9386" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-9359", refs => "ANF" },
 ]
```

and my export to excel output matches whats in the structure.

```
  TNs               REFs
  (111) 111-2493    Z1Z
  (111) 111-4588    no ref
  (111) 111-9355    AMD,ANF
  no ref            (111) 111-9385
  (111) 111-9356    AMD
  no ref            (111) 111-9386
  (111) 111-9359    ANF
```

Comment: I am not concerned about the dump. When I grab the data later on for an csv export the data is in the wrong order.

Comment: The duplicates and the refs are displayed in excel just like the structure... which is no good.

Comment: Would get more help, if you tell us what you want achieve. Hashes has randomized order of keys by design, but it doesn't matter when you using them right.

Comment: @kevin What are you using to get the data from Perl and into Excel?

Comment: I am storing the data in angular and handsontable grids.  Yes, they don't care about the order just the keys.   However, when I export that data from those grids it pulls out the data just as it went it and jacks up the excel.

Comment: Angular just stores the data in a scope var in or out.

Comment: sorry using...  <button class="btn btn-default" ng-csv="db.items" csv-header="getHeader()" field-separator="" filename="acis.csv">Export to CSV</button>.  db.items is the json encoded array of hashes.

Comment: @kevin There's lots of data structures in many languages which do not preserve key order. It could be anywhere in that process. Also anywhere in that process could fix the key order. Showing us some HTML button doesn't help, you have to post the actual code doing all this exporting.

Comment: I am using Mojolicious, so it passing the data back to my html.ep file from a POST to the perl module.

Comment: This is angular and there is no more code for the export. I pass back the @sorted_data, as listed above, from a POST and that data is set to db.items in the response. db.items is a scoped variable in angular and what ever is in that structure is what it will export as well as load into my grid.  That why I need my structure to be correct before I pass it back.

Comment: ***"However, the order of the keys needs to be order and it is not."*** unless you are using the output of `Data::Dumper` then you have no problem. Is there a practical issue, or is it just that you have freaked when looking at the output of `Dumper`?

Comment: As you can see above, in my code, the data dumper output is whats reflected in the export to excel.  Its mixed up because of how the structure is set up.

Answer (score 6):

[Hash keys have no inherent order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Drawbacks), and it's part of why they're so efficient. Their key list must be sorted every time. This is probably the route you want to go.

If you want a hash-like structure that keeps its keys sorted, [look into trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_%28data_structure%29), though there are a dizzying variety.

Alternatively, [Tie::IxHash](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::IxHash) retains its original key order, though at a significant performance cost.

Comment: [Tie::Hash::Indexed](https://metacpan.org/pod/Tie::Hash::Indexed) is a faster alternative to Tie::IxHash, although I don't think either module should be used in the vast majority of cases.

Comment: This did the trick, thanks.  for my $k (sort (keys %data)) {
   tie (my %dataconfig, 'Tie::IxHash','refs' => join( ',', @{ $data{$k} } ),'duplicates' => $k);
   push @sorted_data, \%dataconfig;
 }

Comment: @kevin I still think the real problem lies elsewhere in the export process. In particular, it seems your export to Excel is doing it by order instead of by key. Defeats the point of using a hash.

Answer (score 1):

The data structure you have started with looks like this

```
my %data = (
  '(111) 111-4588' => ['no ref'],
  '(111) 111-9385' => ['no ref'],
  '(111) 111-9355' => ['AMD', 'ANF'],
  '(111) 111-2493' => ['Z1Z'],
)
```

It would have been *far* more useful to have told us this, and given an example of the result that you wanted. Instead I had to write some code to reverse-engineer the information that you gave

The program below seems to be a reasonable replication of your own code, and as you can see the array elements are in order of the `duplicates` elements of their hashes. Within those hashes, as others have observed, the elements are in no particular order

I'm not understanding what more you want? How has the "random order" of has keys been a problem?

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';

use Data::Dump;

my %data = (
  '(111) 111-2493' => ['Z1Z'],
  '(111) 111-4588' => ['no ref'],
  '(111) 111-9355' => ['AMD', 'ANF'],
  '(111) 111-9385' => ['no ref'],
);

my @sorted_data;

for my $k ( sort keys %data ) {
    push @sorted_data, { duplicates => $k, refs => join( ',', @{ $data{$k} } ) };
}

dd \@sorted_data;
```

#### output

```
[
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-2493", refs => "Z1Z" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-4588", refs => "no ref" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-9355", refs => "AMD,ANF" },
  { duplicates => "(111) 111-9385", refs => "no ref" },
]
```

Comment: i guess my response is posted in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

This code solved my issue, thanks.

```
for my $k (sort (keys %data)) {
      tie (my %dataconfig, 'Tie::IxHash','refs' => join( ',', @{ $data{$k} } ),'duplicates' => $k);
      push @sorted_data, \%dataconfig;
    }
```